# Twig Can't Find My Directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, twig

I just installed Twig as part of my own MVC framework. I'm having problems getting it to recognize my directory path when setting up the loader. I tired the following three versions:

```
$twigLoader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../views/user');
$twigLoader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('http://AmColAn.loc/research/views/user');
$twigLoader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/Volumes/Data RAID/htdocs/AmColAn/research/views/user');
```

The first two gave an error that the directory couldn't be found while the third one works fine. Obviously, I'm not going to be able to do this on my production server (godaddy). I suspect I'm doing something simple wrong. It runs on XAMPP on OS X 10.8.2. The twig directory is in the research directory shown in the code. The code is in a file in research/classes.

I also added an .htaccess file to the research directory. It contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

Could this be the problem? I could see it for version 2.

Update: I tried the following:

```
$twigLoader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views/user');
```

This works as well. It seems the starting point for file or directory references is research. I've always had to back out to the base directory with ../'s in all my other php code. The only difference in this case is that there is an .htaccess file. I'd like to know if it's responsible for the behavior and why.

Comment: Where is your index.php located?

Comment: Did you try to use `__DIR__` and a relative path from there?

Comment: It's research/index.php

Comment: I looked up __DIR__ in the online PHP manual. I'm not sure how I could use it here. The code is in research/classes/view.php. I need to tell Twig to use research/views/user as a directory. FYI the underscores around DIR are being stripped out of this comment.

Comment: I meant: did you try this path? `__DIR__ . "/../views/user/"`

Comment: @Maerln: no I didn't, but see the update at the end of my original question. It's a simpler solution, but I don't know why it works, which makes me nervous.